# multiple directives show the same data(scope), how to stop this.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a ng-repeat that will repeat a directive which does a $http call. then it will display the returned data, but I can't seem to stop the directives from updating each other. Here is the idea:

MAIN

```
...ng-repeat='item in itemList'...
    ... my-directive item="item.url"....
```

my-directive template

```
...{{result.count}}..
```

this returns the template updated only when the scope has changed.

```
.directive('myDirective', function($parse, $http) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        item : '='
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    templateUrl: '...template...',
    controller: function($scope) {
$http.get(item.url).success(function(data) {
    result.count=data.count;

})
}
```

at times, the result .count is the same through out the ng-repeat. I will like to know if I am doing something wrong, or maybe there is a way around this?

note: I have checked the results from the http call, and they are different all the time. also there are no syntax errors.

Comment: @ajmajmajma could you send me a link to a good example?

Comment: It looks like you are firing an http call on every singular item inside the repeat. This is not a great way of doing this. Are you forced to do it this way?

Comment: @ajmajmajma sadly, yes. I have to do display data based on a date url which returns specific data which I cannot filter down. My option would be to have one url query which I then can filter down, but not possible. :(

Comment: Just to add onto that last comment - you should do you http calls before you drop the items into the repeat if you can, and preferably in one call, not many individual calls. Then you can hook onto an event of change in the parent scope and control the data there, that way the children you are passing into and binding to the directive will always be consistant. If you have any say I would suggest setting up a backend to use one call. What you are doing here with the repeat and individual html calls is a big no-no.

Comment: I see, so in your opinion, is ALWAYS bad to do an http call in a directive?

Comment: No, doing http call in a directive is fine. Doing individual http calls in a repeat is not so great. But if you're stuck, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `link` in the directive and isolate your scope like:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($parse, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        templateUrl: '...template...',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $http.get(attrs.item).success(function(data) {
                scope.result.count=data.count;
            }),
        }
    }
})
```

Read more about link and isolated scopes on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

---

Like someone said on comments using that is not the best way cos you a doing a GET for each item so if you have 10 items you will do a GET 10 times. **If you can** do the get 1 time on your controller and fetch all the data that you need.

Comment: scope: {
        item : '='
    }, is not the same as attrs.item?

Comment: if you use '=' is two-way data binding so you are changing all your scopes. http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/ this is a great explain about scopes

Comment: Thank you, I believe you gave the best answer. You are right about the binding, some some reason all the scopes updates. :)